# Setting height en width of a Class in OOP Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, class, size

I'm a beginner with OOP coding in javascript.

I'm trying to set a size of a class. But i got an error in my code.

```
    (function($) {

    Block = function() {
        var self = this;
        this.el = $('<div></div>');
    }

    Block.prototype.appendTo = function(parent) {
        this.el.appendTo(parent);
    }

    Block.prototype.setSize = function(width, height) {
        var self = this;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

})(jQuery);
```

This is how i call the class:

```
var block1 = new Block();
block1.appendTo('body').setSize(100,100);
```

In the console i get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setSize' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setSize` on the return value of `appendTo`. However, `appendTo` returns nothing (`undefined`) and as such it throws an Error when you try and call `setSize` on it.

The solution to this is to return the `Block` object from your `appendTo` function, like so:

```
(function($) {

    Block = function(width, height) {
        this.el = $('<div></div>');
        if (width !== undefined && height !== undefined) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }
    }

    Block.prototype.appendTo = function(parent) {
        this.el.appendTo(parent);
        return this;
    }

    Block.prototype.setSize = function(width, height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thank you for your anwser, but i want to set the size with "setSize". So if you do var block1 = new Block();
block1.appendTo('body').setSize(100,100); the size of the div is 100x100 px

Comment: You can - replace my constructed with yours. I did mention that earlier but perhaps it wasn't noticeable enough. The only thing required for this problem is the `width = -1; height = -1;` section

Comment: mabye iam overlooking something, but i got still the same error. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BqNfe/